# can I disable the button using like this in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(this).closest("fieldset").find("input:not(:checkbox), select,textarea").attr('disabled', this.checked);
```

with this I can Disable Input,select,textarea how to do with the button?

thanks

Comment: what do you want to do with the button? disable it,or do you want to disable all the inputs by hitting the button?

Comment: I need to disable Input type="submit"

Comment: rockers - Your code should disable submit too. I updated my example to demonstrate that. If you wanted, you could specify `:submit` in the selector, but not needed if you use `input:not(:checkbox)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/JzKdx/2/ **(updated)**

Were you having some specific issue?

HTML **(updated to include submit button)**

```
<fieldset>

    <input type='checkbox' /> Click me
    <br><br>
    <input type='text' />
    <select>
        <option>one</option>
    </select>
    <textarea>
        sometext
    </textarea>

    <input type='submit' />

</fieldset>
```

jQuery

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).closest("fieldset")
        .find("input:not(:checkbox), select,textarea")
        .attr('disabled', this.checked);  
    });​
```

Comment: Yes pat I do see that. i will try

Answer (score 1):

Not quite - as long as the disabled attribute is present, the control will be disabled. To re-enable the control, you have to remove the disabled attribute. Something like this:

```
var element = $(this).closest("fieldset").find("input:not(:checkbox), select,textarea");
if (this.checked) {
  element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
  element.removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to remove the `disabled` attribute, but not required to my knowledge. Setting true/false (which is what OP is doing) should work too.

Comment: I need to disble type="submit'

<input id="IbtnSubmit" type="submit" class="button" value="Save" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

`$(this).closest("fieldset").find("input:not(:checkbox), select,textarea,button").attr('disabled', this.checked);`